# Вопрос по https://

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Существуют ли варианты для указания изображения на сайте под http:// если сам сайт на https:// ? Например счетчик из определенного топ рейтинга.

Comment: Так и пишите `http://ссылка на изображение`

Comment: В таком случае https не работает полноценно. Пишет что части страницы не защищены. Я имею ввиду не http://ссылка на изображение а <img src>

Comment: Если вам нужно на сайте с https показывать изображения с сайта без https, то у вас есть варианты: либо копировать их все к себе на сайт, либо на своем сайте делайте прокси обертку при обращении к которой загружается изображение со стороннего сайта и отдается пользователю уже по https. В nginx кажется есть встроенные средства для этого.

Comment: Можно подробнее, пожалуйста, насчет второго варианта?

Comment: Вот https://nginx.ru/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html посмотрите про модуль nginx, модет подойдет.

Comment: А что если через CURL это реализовать?

Comment: Достаточно заголовки отправить и использовать http://php.net/manual/ru/function.readfile.php Примеры смотрите на странице документации.

Comment: Могли бы Вы чуть подробнее это все обяснить и направить на правильный путь? Можно с примера что и как? Просто я не совсем разбираюсь в этом. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: То есть какой вариант намного лучше nginx или этот и чтобы нагрузки не было. Мне нужно только одну картинку взять. То есть счетчик из рейтинга. Он на http:// а https не поддерживает.

Comment: @WebMaster если используется https, нужно чтобы код счетчика тоже грузился по https, иначе скрипт просто не загрузится. Что за счетчик такой который не поддерживает https?

Comment: Это старый топ рейтинг, но все еще актуальный в данный момент. Что же можно сделать кроме как отказаться от него :(

Comment: @WebMaster не совсем так. HTTPS работает полностью, но страница, части которой загружаются по небезопасным каналам, считается небезопасной. Тут без вариантов: страница безопасна, только если полностью состоит из материалов из безопасных каналов.

Comment: То есть совсем нет решения?

Comment: Счётчики обычно работают только при их загрузке напрямую, и если они не поддерживают https, то без вариантов. Или просите разработчика счётчика допилить https, или страдайте с не полностью защищённым соединением

Comment: Может все таки есть какой нить обход через CURL подмену?

Comment: Эта подмена станет говорить об одном-единственном посетителе, так что нет

Comment: Чем вам не угодило «https не работает полноценно»?

Comment: Пугает людей :(